# Italy Regional Trains itinerary and routes

Tags: trains, italy, routes, itineraries, train-stations

I will be going on vacation to Italy in late March and April. I am trying to plan my trip, as I'm not yet entriely sure what cities to visit. Lot's of webpages mention regional trains, saying they stop at most towns of any importance in their way between major cities. I would like to know where these trains stop so I can maybe choose to say in one of the towns for a few days. However, I can't find any actual routes or itineraries.

I will arrive in Rome, and I know that I want to visit at least Venice, Florence and Bergamo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't tell you where every possible regional train in the whole of Italy stops, the list would be too long!

For a given train / route though, the easiest way to check is with [Bahn.de, the website of the German railways](http://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/index.shtml). Put in the start station and the end station, then pick a train, then click *Show intermediate stops* to see the stops on the way

Picking Rome to Venice as an example, head to [Bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/index.shtml), enter Rome and Venice and a suitable day (eg a weekday or weekend, or the real date if it's under 3 months away), and get the listing up like this:

[image: DB example]

Then click **Show intermediate stops** and see them, eg

[image: More Example]

Try it out for the routes of interest!

Comment: Exactly the kind of tool I was hoping for, thanks!

Comment: Well, in this example you only have EuroStar listed, which are not regional trains. If you want to have only regional trains in the result, you have to check the checkbox "Local transport".

Answer (score 8):

Use [www.trenitalia.com](http://www.trenitalia.com/). It's the official website of Italian railways. You can find all routes and also buy tickets with credit card.

[image]

This is definitely what you need.

As you can see in the image, in the home page of the site you can search for any departure/arrival station and change the date/time of your trip (note that. The names of the stations are only in Italian. For example you can't search for Rome or Florence, instead you have to search Roma or Firenze). You can also filter the results for train type (All trains, Frecce that means high speed trains or Regional).

Once you choose your search criteria all the possible results will be shown:

[image]

In this section you can choose your preferred option and fare, and finally buy the ticket (I'm quite sure that registration is not needed).

Clicking on the `info` button like indicated in the following image you will see all the stations the train will stop.

[image]

For high speed trains there is also another train company: [Italo](http://www.italotreno.it/)

High speed train cover only the major cities: Naples, Rome, Florence, Milan, Tourin, Bologna, Venice and some others. Instead you can reach quite any town with a regional train, even the smallest ones.
Sometimes you need to take more than one train, but the website will arrange all the train changes for you.

P.S. regional trains can be veeeery slow :)

Very useful are also these mobile applications:

- [Trenitalia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lynxspa.prontotreno&hl=en) - official trenitalia app
- [Train Timetable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.paoloconte.treni_lite&hl=en) - unofficial app, but works better than the official one. Includes also Italo trains
- [Italo Treno](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.italotreno&hl=en) - official Italo app

Comment: Since the OP is struggling, can you show them how to use the site to find what they need?

Comment: Regional trains are as fast as regional trains can be.

Comment: @JoErNanO I just wanted to say that some particular regional trains are slower than others